# No me pinta mi JTABLE

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo este código

```
   DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable();
    dtm.addColumn("NOMBRE");
    dtm.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
    dtm.addColumn("DNI");
    dtm.addColumn("LOCALIDAD");
    dtm.addColumn("PROVINCIA");
    tabla.setModel(dtm);
    contentPane.add(tabla);
```

No consigo que me aparezca la tabla con esas columnas , ¿sabéis cual puede ser el fallo?

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `tabla.setVisible(true);` ?

Comment: Si pero tampoco me lo crea...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar un scrollPane.
por ejemplo:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
    dtm.addColumn("NOMBRE");
    dtm.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
    dtm.addColumn("DNI");
    dtm.addColumn("LOCALIDAD");
    dtm.addColumn("PROVINCIA");
    tabla.setModel(dtm);
    contentPane.add(scroll);
```

Comment: pues tampoco me funciona...

Answer (score 0):

prueba este código, es una pequeña pruena con un frame y un panel, añadiendo la tabla que creaste con tu código al scroll y ese scroll añadiéndolo al panel,

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Alberto Loera
 */
public class JtableStack {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
    dtm.addColumn("NOMBRE");
    dtm.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
    dtm.addColumn("DNI");
    dtm.addColumn("LOCALIDAD");
    dtm.addColumn("PROVINCIA");
    tabla.setModel(dtm);
    panel.add(scroll);
    panel.updateUI();
  }
}
```

Comment: me funciona pero cuando lo meto en mi código me la sigue sin pintar...muchas gracias de todas formas